# Reusing of a Rule in Bison and Flex Grammar

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I was trying to make a Request-response sequence of messages between client and server.
For parsing the messages I was using flex and bison grammar. 
I have a question regarding reusing of a rule in different grammar.
for example if I have a grammar for processing request as

```
req_message:
    request_message
    |response_message
    |error
    ;
```

where request message is

```
request_message:
    |request_header_list request_hdr
```

and request_hdr is

```
request_hdr:
    accept
    |accept_language
    |bandwidth
    |user_agent
    |session
    |cseq
    |cache_control
    ..
    ;
```

similarly for response I have a grammer as

```
response_header:
    cseq
    |session
    |range
    |public
    |server
    |content_type
    ..
    ;
```

For parsing the `cseq`, I have defined only one rule. That rule is working fine while parsing the request. But while parsing the response, the rule is not showing up. Is there anything like, same rule cannot be used for different grammars ? Why is it working for request and not working for response ? In the lex side, I found no problem in parsing the lexims, it is able to return `cseq token` to the yacc

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to diagnose the problem without seeing a little more of your yacc spec.  In particular, it would be helpful to see your production (grammar rule) for `response_message`.  However, even without that information, I notice that your naming is inconsistent.  You have `request_hdr` but `response_header`.  Is that intentional?

Comment: response_header is part of response message sending... I have not defined it in the question. the request header and response header contain different fields thats why I included both.